# i dont understand how the ternary operator is working and how we are calling the function in this array map method

Tags: javascript

i am using this ternary operator in javascript function argument  and i really dont seem to know how it is being used and how the function(fn) is being called.

my understanding is that the typeof fn evaluates to true then we use fn function but to do what?

i really dont get it.

i have tried to read through all the materials available but dont seem to understand how we are ruturning val=> val[fn]

```
const countBy = (arr, fn) =>
arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1;
return acc;
}, {});
console.log(countBy([6, 10, 100, 10], Math.sqrt));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This says if `fn` is function use `fn` use `val => val[fn]`

```
typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]
```

One use case i see is using the same function one to do some arithmetic on array which has numbers, or an array of object with some key names,

```js
const countBy = (arr, fn) =>
  arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
console.log(countBy([6, 10, 100, 10], Math.sqrt));
console.log(countBy([{b:6}, {b:10}, {b:100}, {b:10}], 'b'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Array map() takes a function. The ternary is being used to determine what function to run. The code says if `fn` is a function use it as a function, if not use this other function and it uses it as a key.

The code can be rewritten as

```
const countBy = (arr, fn) => {
  let mapped
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    mapped = arr.map(fn)
  } else {
    mapped = arr.map(val => val[fn])
  }
  return mapped.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Problem here is the variable fn is very unclear what it is. Someone overloaded a function and did not use a good variable name. Personally I would have altered it to be an object.

```js
const countBy = (arr, options) =>
  arr.map(options.processFunction ? options.processFunction : val => val[options.objectProperty]).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[val] = (acc[val] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(countBy([6, 10, 100, 10], {
  processFunction: Math.sqrt
}));


const receipt = [{
  total: 6
}, {
  total: 10
}, {
  total: 100
}, {
  total: 10
}]

console.log(countBy(receipt, {
  objectProperty: 'total'
}));
```

Comment: Is that code overall  considered readable in a normal working environment ?

Comment: It is readable to me. Would need comments to make it clear what it is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

`val` - is object that contains function. You get function: `myObject['myFunction']` which is applied to each element using `map`.

`myObject['myFunction']` equals to `myObject.myFunction`

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` takes a function as an argument. That function gets invoked by `map` for each item in the array. So when you return `fn`, you're telling `map` to run `fn(item)` for each element. Map then returns a new array containing the results of each invocation.